# enum handling on insert with dapper

Tags: c#, dapper

How can i make dapper use the string value of an enum. In the example below it uses the numerical value of the enum. 
On read from the database, dapper correctly converts string to enum.

```
public enum Category { A, B }

public Product 
{ 
    public Category Cat {get;set;}
    public int Id {get;set;}
}

Product p  = new Product() {Cat = Category.A, Id=22} ;
connection.Execute("Insert into Products (Cat, Id) Values ",p);
```

In this case in the database in the column Cat I have value `1` instead of `A`

Comment: Not sure if you can. You cannot with EF, think that Enum are internally represented as numeric values, the name is just something you use from C# code.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way I think is:

```
connection.Execute("Insert into Products (Cat, Id) Values ", new { p.Id, Cat = p.Cat.ToString());
```